# Reliable free and open source container engine, truly operating-system agnostic (alternative to Docker)

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, docker

[Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)) was meant to solve the problem of vendor lock-in and being able to run an application and its dependencies in a virtual container that would work on Windows, Linux or MacOS. However, Docker does not fulfill the purpose:

- **Situation 1:** A Docker container built fine on one AWS EC2 instance (Ubuntu 20), but there were `librdkafka` build errors on another EC2 instance (Ubuntu 22). But this shouldn’t have been a problem, because the Docker container runs Ubuntu 20.
- **Situation 2:** A Docker container with Ubuntu and (I think) an `x64` architecture, didn't build on a MacOS 12 with an `Apple M1 Pro` ARM processor.

Situation2 is at least understandable because of `x86` vs. `ARM`. But Situation1 was bewilderingly shocking.

So my question is simply that since Docker does not serve its purpose, is there a more reliable free and open source alternative we can use to run virtual containers that are truly operating-system agnostic? Ideally, hardware-architecture agnostic too, but that's a hard ask, so at least OS-agnostic.
Additionally, the way we are expected to configure Docker with multiple commands squashed into a single line with ampersands, and the manifest file being prone to typos, and the complexity of entering port numbers, links, ensuring connectivity etc., make Docker cumbersome to use.
Computers were meant to save us time and effort. But the way people design software architecture, it makes us lose more time and effort. I really need a better alternative to Docker (unless the people maintaining Docker can re-architect it to make it simpler, independent and more functional).